# iOS Lite to Paid, migrate core data

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

I've been following this guide for migrating core data between two apps, a free one and a paid  one.

http://mobileorchard.com/lite-to-paid-iphone-application-data-migrations-with-custom-url-handlers/

I've run into a problem with it though. I can get the free version to launch the paid version, but the upgrade data isn't being added to the URL. When i print out the contents of fileData its (null).

Comment: Is the URL received as expected?

Comment: do you mean in the lite version or the paid for one?

Or is there an easier way of doing what i want?

Comment: In the paid version (the receiver). The URL it receives, does it have the full URL. Is the length of data sent the same as the length of data received?

Comment: The problem is the lite one isn't sending any data. The paid for one receives mt://localhost/importDatabase?(null)

Comment: Does the file exist at the path your code thinks it does?

Comment: i believe so. i'm getting the path using
NSString *sqlitePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Medicine_Tracker.sqlite"];
which gives
/Users/ceriturner/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/A3303789-E82D-4D0E-80A8-B89A0B97E8B6/Medicine Tracker Lite.app/Medicine_Tracker.sqlite

Comment: That must be a file released with the app? So it's a placeholder or a template? You can't be saving edits to the model there?

Comment: That's the file created when the persistant store is set up

Comment: You can't create files in the bundle at runtime. Change the code that creates the file (and your code to get the data) to place the file in the app documents directory instead.

Comment: Think I've solved the issue. The file exists in both the main bundle and the user documents.